# SQL query that can create a row for skipped months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that I join to a calendar table, but I need to populate / create new row for each month between. I.e.

```
Date        GIS CODE                            Running Total Open
2007-04-30  BEJOORDING, 6566, WESTERN AUSTRALIA 5
2007-09-30  BEJOORDING, 6566, WESTERN AUSTRALIA 6
```

I need some sort of query that can create end of month date rows between 2007-04-30 and 2007-09-30. 
 I will then need to fill down the blanks with the most recent fields so I will have a timeline for all end of month values.

I am assuming I will have to use some sort of CTE table but I am not the best at this / understand exactly how they work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `left join` on the date to the calendar table

Answer (score 1):

This CTE query will give you a table with all end-of-month values between the first and last ones in your table (I've assumed called `log`). You can then `LEFT JOIN` that to the table to create rows for all months in the timespan.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT MIN(Date) AS [Date], MAX(Date) AS Max_Date FROM log
  UNION ALL
  SELECT EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [Date])), Max_Date
  FROM CTE
  WHERE Date < Max_Date
)
SELECT Date 
FROM CTE
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/488be/1)

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved with a RIGHT JOIN to a subquery against the calendar table using the EOMONTH() function

Comment: Will this work for multiple observations for each date?

Comment: Hard to answer specifically as those details aren't in the question, but yes it's probably managable with GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks. I’ll play with that